# I installed firebase CLI, and upon running firebase I get an "Error: Cannot find module Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry"

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, windows-11

I am on windows 11.
nodejs version 18.8.0
npm version 7.12.0

I installed firebase with this command:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

following this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#windows-npm

This is what I get when I type firebase.

```
C:\Users\username>firebase login
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:371
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\proxy-agent\dist\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:363:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:576:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:803:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:6:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\proxy-agent\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'proxy-agent'
}
```

I have restarted the terminal multiple times. I've tried both terminal inside Visual Studio Code and powershell and cmd terminals. I get the exact same error.

What can I do about this?

EDIT:

I've inspected the first folder that is mentioned in the output above and I noticed that index.js does not exist, instead a file called **index.js.DELETE.c45d6d73bb56d0f5f3a9d282439db740** exists. **Does anyone know why is this?** It seems that npm can't find the index.js since its called something else. Very werid. Hope someone has run into something simillar.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried removing and installing the package again? Also try `npm cache verify` and install again, could be due to corrupt cache.

Comment: it seems removing cache and then trying again twice, did the trick. It finally installed.